# Try Call Dll, But the method has a complicated struct type, I can't define it in .Net

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

The struct define in C++ is:

```
typedef struct _DEVICE_PATH_LIST_
{
    int NumDevice;  
    TCHAR *devicePath[DEVICE_PATH_LIST_SIZE];   
} DEVICE_PATH_LIST;
```

and the C++ function's definition is:

```
 LandiWin_iGetDevicePathList( int iDeviceType, DEVICE_PATH_LIST *  devicePathList);
```

Then I want to call that method, so I need to define a struct that can represent the `DEVICE_PATH_LIST`. Here is my definition in C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct DevicePathType
{
    public int NumDevice;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray,SizeConst=32)]
    public char*[] devicePath;
}
```

but it's not right, I also tried all other type but all failed. please help me define a right struct.

Comment: What if you need to pass more than 32 devices? Is the data passed to the function, or returned by it? It's a very common mistake to believe that a function signature fully defines the interface. You also have to detail the semantics. One good way to do so would be to show example calling code in C++.

Comment: Your [MarshalAs] is good, best to use public IntPtr[] devicePath.  Recover the strings with Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi() *or* Marshal.PtrToStringUni(), depending on how the C code was built.  Probably Ansi given that you have trouble with char*.  Beware that there's a memory management issue, you might leak memory if the strings need to be released by the caller.  Test this by calling the method a million times.  And that you have to get the CallingConvention right, probably Cdecl.

Comment: @HansPassant, thanks. It worked when I use the IntPtr[] to replace the char*[]

Answer (score 0):

The code of C++ like:

```
typedef struct _DEVICE_PATH_LIST_
{
 int NumDevice; 
 TCHAR *devicePath[DEVICE_PATH_LIST_SIZE];  
} DEVICE_PATH_LIST;
```

The code of C# need to be like:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct DevicePathType
{
    public int NumDevice;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 32)]
    public IntPtr[] devicePath;
}
```